# Custom Segue With CATransition

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, catransition

I wrote the following code to have a transition from right to left from one to another view controller. **But the new view controller just appears without animation.**

```
override func perform() {

var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
var destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController

var transition: CATransition = CATransition()

transition.duration = 1.25
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

destinationViewController.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

I just can't find any mistake. Can anyone find one? Am I missing something simple?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

change this code:

```
destinationViewController.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
```

to the new one:

```
destinationViewController.view.window!.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
```